# Changing the applications launched by special keyboard buttons

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, cinnamon

I'm running 14.04 with Cinnamon.  When I press the "my computer" button on my Dell keyboard, it launches the vanilla GNOME Files file manager.  I want to make it launch Cinnamon's Nemo.

I'm finding a lot of answers about what the common keyboard shortcuts are, but not how to change what app responds to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings page, there's a keyboard shortcuts section where you can remap all your shortcuts.

Comment: If you're referring to the Keyboard section in the settings, that lets you change the mapping from key combo to named action.  I want to change the mapping from named action (apparently "XF86Explorer" in this case) to application.

Comment: If you add a custom keyboard shortcut and bind `XF86Explorer` to `nemo`, it *might\* override the default binding.

Comment: I changed the "Home folder" binding from `XF86Explorer` to `unassigned` and then created a custom shortcut as you suggested.  The name it gave to the keyboard binding when I set it by pressing the button was `Explorer`.